# Orbeon Forms: Global/Application Libraries and Actions & Dialogs

Tags: orbeon

We've just come to realise that any Actions/Dialogs that are embedded in the Global or Application Libraries (GL/AL) do not work when these template sections are used in the forms (see [here](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/advanced/section-templates)).

The actions are between the `</xf:instance>` and `</xf:model>` labels. And the dialogs are before the last `</fr:section>` label at the bottom of the XML code.

Is there any workarounds for this issue, or any advice you can offer.

Thanks in advance.

PeteA

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are referring to custom code using the [action syntax](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-builder/advanced/services-and-actions/actions-syntax) or custom dialogs that you added to the source of the form.

As of this writing, supporting the action syntax is already mostly implemented, and is currently planned for Orbeon Forms 2023.1, and a backport to the 2022.1 is also planned. You might want to check issue [#4814](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/4814) for the most up-to-date information.